# Best practice in handling invalid parameter CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling

Let's say I have a method at Controller named

```
book($chapter,$page);
```

where $chapter and $page must be integer. To access the method, the URI will look like

```
book/chapter/page
```

For example,

```
book/1/1
```

If user try to access the URI without passing all parameter, or wrong parameter, like

```
book/1/
```

or
    book/abcxyz/1

I can do some if else statements to handle, like

```
if(!empty($page)){
   //process
}else{
   //redirect
}
```

My question is, is there any best practice to handle those invalid parameters passed by user? **My ultimate goal is to redirect to the main page whenever there is an invalid parameter**? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the CodeIgniter routing in `config/routes.php` is pretty useful here, something like this:

```
$route['book/(:num)/(:num)'] = "book/$1/$2";
$route['book/(:any)'] = "error";
$route['book'] = "error";
```

Should catch everything.  You can have pretty much any regular expressions in the routes, so can validate that the parameters are numeric, start with a lowercase letter, etc..

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I'm looing for!

Comment: Just be careful when using routes for every simple thing as it may create a lot of mess later.

Answer (score 3):

The best logic here seems to be adding the default values:

```
book($chapter = 1, $page = 1);
```

and then checking if they are [numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

So it automatically opens the 1st page of the 1st chapter if there are parameter missing or non-numeric.

Comment: yes, it is true. We can also do something like $page = $this->uri->segment(4, 1); //Where 2nd parameter is the default value if the parameter is missing